# Limitations on regex in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I had a rewrite rule on Apache for `/year/month/date` links in a form that specifically defined 4 digits, then 2 digits, then 2 digits, that looked like this:

```
^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/$
```

On nginx this regex causes an error that says the whole line is not terminated by a `;` sign, until i remove the `{}` brackets and leave the regex like this:

```
^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$
```

Is this limitation intentional on nginx's part or some mistake on my part?

The whole line from Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/$ index.php?page=date&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3
```

The whole (working) line from nginx:

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?page=date&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite